# Javascript click on <body> - Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have have JavaScript like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/3976/) and I now want to add one more function to improve it. I want to add function that will on click on body but not on `red dot`, alert user.

-Exactly When User click on RED DOT function won't alert him, but if he miss RED DOT script will alert him. Thats will look: If `<body>` is clicked but .a not alert("Error");  Thanks a lot. I have googled for it but no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the event listener to the body, making sure that the target is not the `.a` div. Use something like this:

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
  if(event.target != $('div.a')[0])
    alert('You clicked the body!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just bind a click listener to the window and check which element has been clicked.

```
window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target != document.querySelector('div.a')){
    alert('Error');
  }
});
```