# Show and hide over all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="box">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="temp" />
        <div class="list">
            focus <br />
            two <br />
            three
        </div>
        <div class="info">Test info </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="temp" />
        <div class="list">
            test1
            two <br />
            three
        </div>
        <div class="info">Test info </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="temp" />
        <div class="list">
            test2
            two <br />
            three
        </div>
        <div class="info">Test info 444</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ykw67nuv/1/

How can I show div.desc over all divs (position: absolute) in this example? I would like div.desc immediately below input (over div.info etc).

Second question: how can I hide div.desc if I click outside input.temp?

Comment: jQuery has `.offset()` to get and set the absolute position of elements

Comment: To answer your second question, refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32445720/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.temp').focus(function(){                              // on focus...
   $(this).closest('div').find('.desc').css({             // Get desc
       top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()  // set Y pos
   }).show();                                             // and show it.
}).blur(function(){                                       // On blur...
   $(".desc").hide();                                     // hide all.
});
```

```css
.desc {
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;                                    /* add this */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="temp" />
        <div class="info">Test info </div>
        <div class="desc">
            focus <br />
            two <br />
            three
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="temp" />
        <div class="info">Test info </div>
        <div class="desc">
            test1
            two <br />
            three
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="temp" />
        <div class="info">Test info 444</div>
        <div class="desc">
            test2
            two <br />
            three
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the input box currently focused in and position your .desc element accordingly then. Do not forget to get the .desc element a `position:absolute`

```
$('.temp').focus(function(){
   $(this).parent('div').find('.desc').toggleClass('show').css({
    left:$(this).position().left,
       top:$(this).position().top+$(this).height()+10,
       width:($(this).width()+10)+'px'
   });
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').find('.desc').toggleClass('show');
})
```

Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ykw67nuv/3/